# I've tried everything, but I just can't limit the maximum Java RAM usage

Tags: java, ram

I've read all the other questions here about this, and many articles on the rest of the internet. According to [this site](https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx), the maximum memory usage follows this formula:

```
Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss]
```

Flags I've tried:

```
-Xss[16-128M] 
-XX:MetaspaceSize=[64-256M] -XX:MaxMetaSpace=[64-256M]
-XX:PermSize=[128-256M] -XX:MaxPermSize[128-256M]
```

Still, when I launch my Java application with -Xmx2G and all of these flags, RAM usage slowly climbs to 6+ GBs, and eventually stops or freezes when it can't allocate more than my 8GB system has.

Background: Program is a game and I'm running Linux and Java 8.

Comment: [Direct Byte Buffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) don't count to the JVM. Also, any native (JNI) code you may be calling can also allocate as much memory as it wants.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the JVM allocates more memory than just what is specified by the max Heap size.

Comment: Do you know how many threads there are?  - On Linux you might run your app (perhaps in an Emacs shell) using strace to see whether the program uses system calls to allocate memory beyond heap, stack etc.

Comment: jstack output: https://gist.github.com/ajthemacboy/f3797b42678a8cb6a4e7

VisualGC: http://i.imgur.com/DfKoNKl.png

I don't know much about interpreting this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the visualvm plugin for buffer pools. You can see how much direct and mapped memory is allocated

Comment: It doesn't seem like that much. The mapped memory used is 0 bytes, and the direct memory used is about 0.14 GBs. How should I interpret this data?

Comment: What's the behaviour of the heap is it growing or stable while your java process is consuming all that memory?

Comment: Once the program finishes loading the RAM tops off at about 3Gbs. When I login to a world the memory slowly increases to up to 7GBs before it gets too slow to play and I pkill. The heap remains stable at 2300 MBs, which is the value of my -Xmx.

Comment: can you attach jconsole to your application? It contains a tab called memory, at least in jdk7 distribution. In that tab you can select non-heap-memory-usage that should be more general respect to mapped/direct referred to java.nio. In fact I'm monitoring my local tomcat with 0 bytes used in java.nio and with 45M used as non-heap-memory-usage.

Comment: Last tentative I have in mind is  ssh to your remote server and type pmap PID in the console. This give to you the full map of the memory used by the process identified by PID. Check if something is consuming abnormal memory

Comment: The problem I'm running into with pmap is that the largest RAM consuming files are listed as anon. Anyway to find out what they really are?

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult for me guessing it. Do you ave any library that is using off-heap memory?

Comment: I am not the developer of the game (it's heavily modded Minecraft.) I'm sure one of the mods does, but I don't know how to track it down.